# Calculating string length not correct when not printing out the return value of a program

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

Length is suppose to return how far along the counter went when going trough the string. However, it only returns the correct value when it is printed beforehand. If i comment out the `printf` it returns 0.
Does anyone have an explanation for this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100

int length(char *s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        printf("%d ", i);           //<-- here
    return i;
}

int main() 
{
    char s[MAX];
    fgets(s, (char)sizeof(s), stdin);
    s[strcspn(s, "\n")]='\0';
    printf("Length: %d\n", length(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's why you always use brackets `{}` ^^

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, if you comment out the `printf()` statement in the `length()` function, the `return` statement becomes part of the loop body, and the very first iteration returns from the call and you get the *the-then* value of `i`, which is just the entry value for the loop, `0`.

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    //printf("%d ", i);           //<-- here
return i;                         // without brace-enfoced scope, this is the loop body.
```

is the same as

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
return i;
```

What You need is the loop to complete the execution, hit the exit criteria and then, execute the `return` statement with the latest value of `i`.

So, to avoid the problem, you can enforce empty execution of the loop, by something like

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) ;   // notice the ; here, ends the scope.
return i;
```

or, even better (for the readers)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {/*nothing here*/}       //indicates empty loop body
return i;
```

---

Note: As an alternative way, to enhance the readability, instead of a `for` construct you can also make use of `while` loop, which goes like

```
while (s[i] != '\0') 
{
    i++;                     //increment statement is explicit.
}
```

Comment: So what you are saying, if i don't have a semicolon, regardless of how far, the first statement after the loop will get executed. Correct?

Comment: Here is one situation where while loop should be used instead of for loop where increment Takes place inside the braces.

Comment: @Michi You mean to say, make the increment of the index explicit by putting it as the loop body for `while` construct, right?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh. Right. :))

Answer (score 5):

In a loop like this:

```
for (...)
    statement1;
statement2;
```

`statement1` will be the only thing executed in the loop. When you comment out the `printf` call, `return i;` is executed on the very first iteration, immediately returning zero.

Notice, however, that `statement1` can be empty, so, to run a loop with no body, do:

```
for (...)
    ; // yes, a hanging semicolon

// or like this:
for (...);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just commnt out that `printf`, you will be left with this:

```
int length(char *s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    return i;
}
```

This is equal to:

```
int length(char *s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        return i; // returns in the first iteration, without even incrementing i once
    }
}
```

Surely this isn't what you intended. Instead, put a semicolon after the `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i);
```

This way, `for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i);` won't accidentally affect a following statement.

You can prevent such accidents by adding explicit braces to denote your intention, for instance:

```
int length(char *s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", i);           //<-- here
    }
    return i;
}
```

Now if you remove the `printf` line, it doesn't affect the program execution in any other way than omitting the print.

Comment: Even better is to always use explicit braces on loops, conditions etc, then problems like this cannot occur. In perl for example, explicit braces are even mandatory.

Comment: Good suggestion, I added a version of how the function could look like this way.